# Hidden patterns in the natural numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, pattern-recognition

Consider the matrix $\{a_{ij}\}_{i,j\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $a_{ij} = 1$ iff $i \equiv 0\,\text{mod}\,j$. Drawing it with stretched y-axis by a factor of $5$ reveals some "waves" which I referred to as "hidden patterns" in the title of this question.

[image]

The fronts of three distinguishable waves "travel" into three directions:

[image]

My question is threefold:

1. How can these patterns be explained in general terms of (modular) arithmetic?
2. How do I have to color the dots in the adjacency matrix such that dots on the same wave front have the same color? That means: For which function $f:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $a_{ij} = f(i,j)$ do we have $a_{ij} = a_{kl}$ iff $a_{ij}, a_{kl}$ lie on the same wave front (wherever there *is* a distinguished wave front).
3. How can the slopes of the directions of the waves (i.e. of the colored lines) be calculated? Note that even with a stretching factor of $5$ the slopes are quite small.

For larger stretching factors the wave travelling into the green direction becomes unrecognizable. Four wave fronts of the wave travelling into the orange direction are highlighted.

[image]

Without stretching you almost see nothing:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you change the "5"?

Comment: @Randall I was wondering the same thing as it could be an artifact of the number 5. Does the same pattern show up at 6 and 7 times stretched?

Comment: @Randall: The top most figures are with stretching factor 5, the third with factor 20, the last is without stretching.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: I'm quite sure that it's not an artifact of 5.

Comment: Notice that the different wavy regions in your image overlap each other and "can be seen either way" where they overlap. I think each of these patterns in a sense occupies the entire grid and can be made visible in different places (and with different "slopes") depending on how you stretch the image, so your questions about the visible wavefronts may be ill-posed. The effect seems related to [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).

Comment: @Karl: Could you sketch or explain on which other wavefronts the dots marked in the last figure may lie? There surely are many dots that lie on different wavefronts, but for some of them the wavefront might be unique.

Comment: I can imagine continuing each wavefront farther downward from where it appears clearly. Rotating each of your 20px vertical segments (to have a small positive slope, say) would "reveal" this continuation.

Comment: So to answer your question, the marked dots also belong to the wave pattern above the one they're obviously in.

Comment: @Karl I think this is aliasing too. You can see clear lines sampled at regular intervals so the analogy with line rasterization seems reasonable.  The waves may be a stroboscopic effect or Moiré pattern.

Comment: @Karl: Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Randall: Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. At the heart of the patterns is the identity $n^2 - k^2 \equiv 0 \mod (n\pm k)$. The right-most dots $a_{ij} = 1$ on the wave fronts along the orange line have $i = j^2$. The right-most dots on the wave fronts along the other directions have $i = 2\,j^2$ (blue) and $2\,i=j^2$ (green).
2. Giving those dots $a_{ij}$ with $i = n^2 - k^2$, $j = n\pm k$ the color $n$ makes the wave fronts distinguished and reveal that they are parabolas:
   [image]
   Since natural numbers may be written in [zero to many ways as the difference of two squares](https://oeis.org/A100073), some $a_{ij}$ lie on no and some lie on several parabolas.
3. The orange line itself is in fact a parabola rotated by 90 degrees.